# Android & OpenGL ES 2.0: How do I to create multiple puzzle pieces and control them by finger?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, puzzle

I'm new to android programming and I'm trying to create a puzzle game. In my game I have puzzle pieces that I want to drag and move around with my finger. The each puzzle piece are objects that has its own position. I draw the objects by putting them inside a list, then iterate through the list and draw each object separately. My questions is since each object is separate, how do I move them with my finger? Are there any libraries that I should look into?

```
public class GameRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{ 


public GameRenderer()
{   
    //create my puzzle objects here and put them in a list
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) 
{
   //code to setup the surface
}   

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) 
{
   //code to change the viewport when surface resizes
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) 
{
   //iterate through my loop to draw each puzzle piece

}

}
```

Comment: did you ever successfully create jigsaw puzzle pieces? I have done so using masks, but I am curious to know if openGL has anything to offer for this.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need 3rd-party libraries just to drag puzzle pieces around, if I'm inferring correctly from your question that you already have your own OpenGL code working to render some puzzle pieces.

Instead, read up on Android's [MotionEvent class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) that describes the input events you can get for fingers moving around on the touchscreen.  These events should tell your app where the pieces need to move.

Also, check out the sample applications that ship with the Android SDK.  There are some simple games and demos in there, and they show a lot of the Android API in action.  The reference docs themselves are mostly devoid of working example code, so you have to look through the sample apps for that.

Good luck!